# Выбор значений С По из запроса SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite3

К примеру у меня есть запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID >= 5 && ID <= 15;
```

В качестве ответа, я получаю список допустим 1000 (или куда больше до миллионов может быть) элементов, но мне нужно выбрать из них значения с порядковым номером с 100 по 300.

Пока я решил данную проблему следующим образом:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TmpMyTable (ID INTEGER, MyValue TEXT);
INSERT INTO TmpMyTable SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID >= 5 && ID <= 15;
SELECT * FROM TMP_Smile_Data_3 WHERE rowid >= 100 AND rowid <= 300;
```

Но мне не нравится что пришлось создавать новую таблицу (пусть и временную) Можно ли решить эту задачу как нибудь более просто без создания новой таблицы ?

Речь идет про Sqlite базу данных. Пишу приложение на C# для стыковки использую System.Data.Sqlite.
Так же одним из критериев для меня - не хочу что бы операции с базой сильно загружали оперативку, по этому хочу делать все на стороне базы, а не в C#

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID >= 5 && ID <= 15) WHERE rowid >= 100 AND rowid <= 300`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Неа, не выйдет. rowid - это поле создаваемое незримо самой SQLITE оно показывает порядковый номер строки. Когда произворидся первая выборка ELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID >= 5 && ID <= 15 - rowid для этой выборки сохраняется тем же. Т.е. получается что rowid равно к примеру 5,15,25,45 ... 1258. А для моих целей нужно что бы либо rowid вновь от 1 до N формировалось, либо как то иноче научиться тягать строки с 100 по 300

Comment: как раз по этому и думал создать новую таблицу, но мне не нравится этот вариант...

Comment: Ага, судя по всему придется-таки действовать через временную таблицу: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12234791/6766879 Либо использовать более полноценную БД

Comment: А чем обычное [`LIMIT ... OFFSET ...`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) не подходит?

Comment: @Yaant Да подошло, как раз то что нужно. Не когда ранее не пользовался ими просто.